# Excel Random Number Generator Without Producing Duplicates?

Tags: excel, random, duplicates, numbers, generator

[image: Example Screenshot]

I have a column (D2:D49) using the code

> =INT(RANDBETWEEN(0,51))

The idea is that this corresponds to playing card values from a deck.

The only issue is that numbers can appear more than once, meaning there is a chance of being dealt the exact same card (e.g. 4 of spades) twice in one hand, which is impossible - how can I amend the formula to avoid duplicates?

Comment: Please check https://www.listendata.com/2013/02/excel-generating-unique-random-numbers.html

Comment: Many thanks, the RANK function seemed to work best for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the numbers 1 to 51 in one column. In an adjacent column put the formula =RAND(). Sort both columns on the RAND column to get a randomly sorted set of numbers from 1 to 51.